# Android Studio include tag - invalid layout reference

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I want to include one layout file in another. I made a layout view_camera_and_title.xml. I can render it in design window in Android Studio, everything works correctly.

But when I'm trying to include it in another layout file (it's named fragment_note.xml) and run application I'm getting a InflateException with the following error: **android.view.InflateException: You must specifiy a valid layout reference. The layout ID @layout/view_camera_and_title is not valid**.

I saw all topics on stackoverflow with the same error but nothing works for me. I tried to clean project, to restart Android Studio. All my layout files and id_values have no uppercase symbols. No result.

My include tag is without android prefix:

```xml
<include layout="@layout/my_layout"/>
```

These are my layout files:

view_camera_and_title.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="16dp">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/note_photo"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:cropToPadding="true"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/note_camera"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/note_title_label"
            style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/note_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/note_title_hint"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_note.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include layout="=@layout/view_camera_and_title"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/note_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/note_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/note_solved"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/note_solved_label"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/note_partner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:text="@string/note_partner_text"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/note_partner_call"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:text="@string/note_no_partner_call_text"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/note_sharing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:text="@string/note_sharing_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Does anybody know solution for this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `<include layout="=@layout/view_camera_and_title"/>`. I think it should be `<include layout="@layout/view_camera_and_title"/>`, '=' is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray '=' character in:

```
<include layout="=@layout/view_camera_and_title"/>
```